# How do I set cooldown for database based comands

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make a economy bot where I have commands like work which needs cooldown for about 2-3 hr. Command runs well but when I restart the bot or the bot goes offline, the cooldown resets.

I tried to make a `checker function` where I saved `current datatime` and added `60 seconds` to it (for testing purposes) . Here's code:

```py
@client.command()
async def ok(ctx):
    current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    final_time = current_time + datetime.timedelta(seconds=30)
    await client.cd.upsert({"_id":ctx.author.id,"cd_time":final_time})
    await ctx.send(final_time)
```

```py
@tasks.loop(seconds=30)
async def checker(self,ctx):
    ab=await client.cd.find({})
    current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    async for a in ab:
        if current_time >= a["cd_time"]:
            await ctx.send("ok")
        else:
            await ctx.send("on cd")

checker.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

Save your cooldown data properly and retrieve, so it won't get resets when bot goes offline or restart at time.

You can add something like which will fix your issue:

```
@client.command()
async def ok(ctx):
    current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    final_time = current_time + datetime.timedelta(seconds=30)
    await client.cd.update_one(
        {"_id": ctx.author.id},
        {"$set": {"cd_time": final_time}},
        upsert=True
    )
    await ctx.send(final_time)

@tasks.loop(seconds=30)
async def checker(self, ctx):
    ab = await client.cd.find({})
    current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    async for a in ab:
        if current_time >= a["cd_time"]:
            await ctx.send("OKAY!")
        else:
            await ctx.send("ON COOLDOWN!")
```